# How do you force Jenkins Ansible Plugin to set log level

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to set ansible playbook execution to verbose *-vvv* when jenkins runs the playbook via the Ansible Plugin.

However, https://github.com/jenkinsci/ansible-plugin doesn't appear to have a verbose or log level as a part of it and I don't see any other way to push the *-vvv* element on to command line.

Is there a way to set log level in the playbook itself?

Comment: I cannot run this myself, but can you add `extras = '-vvv'` to your `ansiblePlaybook` function call? As in example: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ansible-plugin#example-1

Comment: thanks that was it.

Comment: Good! Converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To set Jenkins Ansible Plugin log level in Pipeline Script you can use `extras` parameter in `ansiblePlaybook` function to add command line arguments. Example:

```
node {
    ansiblePlaybook( 
        playbook: 'path/to/playbook.yml',
        extras: '-vvv' )
}
```